# case in mysql is not working while using is null

Tags: mysql

i am trying display xxx while column is null or empty in mysql,i used case to find out whether column is empty or not but column still returns empty instead of xxx,I am trying to use the below code but it is not working for me. please help me to sort it out.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN t.`rate` IS NULL  THEN 'xxx'
WHEN t.`rate`=5 THEN 2
ELSE 3
END rate FROM `kob_tax` t 
WHERE t.`id_country` = 110 AND t.`id_state` IN(0) AND t.`id_tax_rules_group`=5
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `rate`?

Comment: I don't see any way this can return empty. It should return either `xxx`, `2`, or `3`, nothing else.

Comment: You probably need another WHEN for testing empty cells. `WHEN t.rate = '' THEN 'xxx'`.

Comment: Your query works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c462/1

Comment: Yeah, even changing the type to allow for empty cells as a varchar always results in 3. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/366671/1 are you sure you've worded the question correctly?

Comment: @veeran Please post a SQL fiddle of your data. So that we can better figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement should be written like this.

```
  SELECT
   CASE 
     WHEN t.`rate` IS NULL THEN 'xxx'
     WHEN t.`rate`=''  THEN 'xxx'
     WHEN t.`rate`='5' THEN '2'
     ELSE '3'
   END 
   as rate FROM `kob_tax` t 
  WHERE t.`id_country` = 110 AND t.`id_state` IN(0) AND t.`id_tax_rules_group`=5
```

Refer this demo example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19f500/1/0

**Note:** You have said the `rate` value can be empty. As far as I have tried and know, the columns with number data types such as `INT` or other consider empty value as invalid. Hence I am assuming the rate to be `varchar`.

Comment: If the column is nullable, it can be empty by putting `NULL`. See my sqlfiddle.

Comment: Even if it's varchar, how could his original query fail? If the value is `''` it should go to the `ELSE` clause and return `3`, not an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar the OP has not specified whether the data type is int or varchar. From the query it appears to be int but from his wordings ("empty") it appears to be varchar. I thought he might be writing a wrong query for varchar data type. So, I answered it as usual by demonstrating the same. Let the OP decide you guys had already asked for clarification.........

Comment: @Barmar Empty and NULL are two different things in db. while empty is still a value in dB, NULL means the value is not known.

Comment: What difference does it make what the datatype is? The result can never be empty with his query, because none of the `WHEN` clauses returns an empty string.

Comment: @Barmar I agree with your second comment....waiting for the OP to respond.

Comment: @geeksal the rate is not varchar it is decimal, yes the case query works fine.but what happens when the data in where clause is not available.

Comment: @veeran In your case if any of the where condition is false then the select statement will return zero rows or empty set because you are using `AND` operator.

Comment: @geeksal ok, i understood but is there any option to return some value if the there is no row